# Given $\det(A+B) = 0$ or $\det(AB) = 0$, what can be said for $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Given $\det(A+B) = 0$, what can be said for $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$?

I was thinking that one is maybe the inverse of the other? Im honestly so confused and new at this :c

> Given $\det(AB) = 0$, what can you say for $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$?

for the second part I wrote that if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices then one of them has $\det$ $0$, if they are not the $\det$ is undefined. is that right? thanks in advance

Comment: I apologise I am new here and just wanted to check my 2nd part. sorry.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it

Comment: Thanks everyone for your great and quick response I dont know how to close this or um mark it as answered? :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say nothing for the first question.

- Both can be invertibile if say $A=I$ and $B=-I$.
- No one is invertibile if say $A=0=B$.
- One is and second is not invertibile if say $A = I$ and $B= \pmatrix{-1&0\\0&0}$.

---

For the second, since we have $\det(AB)= \det(A)\det(B)$ then clearly one is not invertibile.

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate it <3

Comment: Thank you ......

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the second is correct. The determinant is only defined for square matrices, and $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$, so if $\det(AB)=0,$ one of $\det(A)$ or $\det(B)$ is $0$.

As for sums, in general, you can't say anything about $\det(A)$ or $\det(B)$ given knowledge of $\det(A+B)$. Take for example
$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
2 &  0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right] \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad 
B=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0&0&0&2\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]
$$
Both have a determinant of $2$, but $\det(A+B)=0$. This will in fact be the case no matter what the top left entry of $A$ or the top right entry of $B$ is.

Comment: Thank you so much as well

Answer (score 0):

1) If it is given **det(A+B)=0** it is not necessary that **det(A)=0** or **det(B)=0** independently.

2) If **det(AB)=0** Either **det(A)=0** or **det(B)=0** as rules of Matrices clearly state **det(AB)=det(A)*det(B)**

Comment: Thanks buddy and Detective conan is bae

Comment: Welcome Buddy <3 Conan Fan wow <3